# Error building WebRTC from source for Android

Tags: android, macos, webrtc, chromium

I'm running into an issue getting webrtc from Chromium set up and building locally. When running `gclient sync`, I get the following error:

```
________ running 'python3 src/build/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-sysroot.py --arch=i386' in '/Users/nbishop/code/ex/webrtc_custom/build_webrtc/webrtc/android'
Installing Debian sid i386 root image: /Users/nbishop/code/ex/webrtc_custom/build_webrtc/webrtc/android/src/build/linux/debian_sid_i386-sysroot
Downloading https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-linux-sysroot/toolchain/23d12100f83139fc55349a841214d5d0bbd85a8d/debian_sid_i386_sysroot.tar.xz
Failed to download https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-linux-sysroot/toolchain/23d12100f83139fc55349a841214d5d0bbd85a8d/debian_sid_i386_sysroot.tar.xz
Error: Command 'python3 src/build/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-sysroot.py --arch=i386' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /Users/nbishop/code/ex/webrtc_custom/build_webrtc/webrtc/android
Installing Debian sid i386 root image: /Users/nbishop/code/ex/webrtc_custom/build_webrtc/webrtc/android/src/build/linux/debian_sid_i386-sysroot
Downloading https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-linux-sysroot/toolchain/23d12100f83139fc55349a841214d5d0bbd85a8d/debian_sid_i386_sysroot.tar.xz
Failed to download https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-linux-sysroot/toolchain/23d12100f83139fc55349a841214d5d0bbd85a8d/debian_sid_i386_sysroot.tar.xz
```

This is on Mac. I can download the tar.xz's just fine, but for some reason the script fails on this portion. `python --version` returns 2.7.16, though I've also tried it with python aliased to python3 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like webrtc for android can only be built on Linux, and that's why gclient sync / install build tools is not working on MacOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).